# MySQL Query -- based on user and business ID's

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project right now and am rather stumped with a specific sql query I (need) to execute. Let me start off by showing the DB structure I need to pull from.

```
    --posts_table--
    ID
    post_title
    post_text
    bus_id
```

This next table is what is screwing with me. The only way data related to the logged in user is in here is if they have "liked" a specific post -- otherwise there is no data related to that user in this table. Now there could be plenty of data related to a particular post, just generated from other users.

```
    --likes_table--
    ID
    user_id
    post_id
    like
```

What I need this to do is grab all the posts from the post_table above where a specific business id is specified. From there, I need it to grab the "like" column in the likes_table if there is data in there related to the logged in user. If there is no data there, just leave that field null in the query. Below is a query I wrote that works until there is other "like" data in the like_table from other users.

```
    SELECT posts.id, posts.post_text, posts.post_title, likes.post_id, likes.like
        FROM posts LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id WHERE
        posts.bus_id = 1 AND likes.user_id IS NULL OR likes.user_id = 1;
```

This works up until data has been entered in the table about a specific post being liked by a different user before that user has done anything with that post, whether they like or dislike it. I am not sure if this specific type of query is even possible, any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

After looking at it again -- I got it, finally. I just needed to add one more AND. Below is the proper query I was looking for.

```
    SELECT posts.id, posts.post_text, posts.post_title, likes.post_id, likes.like
    FROM posts LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id AND posts.user_id = 1 WHERE
    posts.bus_id = 1 AND likes.user_id IS NULL OR likes.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why your query "doesn't work" -- can you give a small snippet of a `posts_table` and `likes_table` that reproduces your problem?  So, if (say) post 1 has bus_id 1 but likes by users other than user_id 1, what does your query return and why is that wrong?

Comment: Sorry -- it was kind of hard to explain, let me try and clarify. It would work and return the post data -- if and only if there was no data in the likes table related to that post from another user.

Comment: I get you - figured it out as you did. Note you don't need the `likes.user_id IS NULL OR likes.user_id = 1` in your `WHERE` condition any more once you add it in to the `LEFT JOIN`. (You solved your own question -- feel free to post your answer as an answer and then accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I *think* I get you -- is it that if a particular post hasn't been commented on by `user_id` number 1 at all, the row for that doesn't show up at all?

In that case, put your `l.user_id=1` into the JOIN condition instead of the WHERE condition --- this will put a `NULL` in if `user_id` 1 hasn't liked or disliked a particular post.

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_text, p.post_title, l.post_id, l.likes
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN likes l ON p.id = l.post_id AND l.user_id=1
  WHERE p.bus_id = 1
```

The `l.user_id IS NULL OR l.user_id=1` has been incorporated into the `LEFT JOIN` -- it doesn't make rows for the other `user_id`s.